# find command doesn't find (readable) files as non-root user

Tags: find

I'm trying to figure out why `find` does not find my files, even when they are readable.

I have the following directory `/some` set up

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Sep 23 16:45 some
```

It's readable by everybody. Inside the directory I have one file called `foundme.txt`

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root student 157961 Sep 23 16:48 foundme.txt
```

Now, when I try to find this file as user student, I don't get any results other than permission errors. My understanding was that the directory and file were readable by student (and they are).

Can someone explain why this is failing?

```
$ find / -name "foundme.txt"
find: ‘/root’: Permission denied
```

Comment: `find` doesn't need to read the file foundme.txt, it just has to be able to list the contents of the directories; are you able to do `find /some` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find` command starts at the top of the filesystem tree `/`, and searches for a file called `foundme.txt`. On its way to the `/some` folder it will include `/root` and a number of other directories that you do not have permission to access (for example, many of the pseudo-directories underneath `/proc`).

Accordingly, `find` warns you that it couldn't check those directories for the file.

If you leave `find` long enough it will discover your file as `/some/foundme.txt`. You can also discard the error/warning messages by appending `2>/dev/null` to the end of the command (this instructs the shell to send everything written to *stderr* to the bit bucket rather than display it on the screen).

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I could hit myself right now. The file is found, but it's hidden in the warnings. For some reason, I was expecting that the file command would show the file at the end of the output. Thanks and sorry about that!